# c3 scatter plot - how can I give a point a name?

Tags: d3.js, c3

On a c3 scatter plot, I can give each point an x and y value, but I also need to give them a name.

I'm passing in json data that looks something like this:

```
[
  {
   name: 'Some Name 1',
   x: 209,
   y: 50
 }
 {
   name: 'Some Name 2',
   x: 100,
   y: 86
  }
]
```

Is there any way to get the name of the point on mouseover? I'm looking for a way that accounts for the possibility that two points have the same x and y values.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have something like this:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(array)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("x",function(d){return d.x;})
  .attr("y",function(d){return d.y;});
```

You would add something like this:

```
.attr("title",function(d){return d.name;});
```

To get:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(array)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("x",function(d){return d.x;})
  .attr("y",function(d){return d.y;})
  .attr("title",function(d){return d.name;});
```

If your data set has a lot of overlapping values. I would change the "name:" element into an array. Then combine any overlapping points into a single object.
So:

```
[
  {
   name: ['Some Name 1'],
   x: 209,
   y: 50
 },
 {
   name: ['Some Name 2'],
   x: 209,
   y: 50
  }
]
```

Would become:

```
[
  {
   name: ['Some Name 1','Some Name 2'],
   x: 209,
   y: 50
  }
]
```

And your d3 code would become:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(array)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("x",function(d){return d.x;})
      .attr("y",function(d){return d.y;})
      .attr("title",function(d){
          var title = "";    
          title = title + d[0];          
          for(var i = 1; i < d.length; i++){
              title = title + ", " + d[i];              
          }
          return title;
       });
```